# 'has contents that are not what they are reported to be' - Getting this error when trying to upload a JPEG file (Image file) using RestAssured

Tags: rest, postman, backend, multipart, rest-assured

I need to make a call to an endpoint using Restassured with a JPEG(Image file) file as multipart/form-data(content type). In the postman, the call is working fine, but its not the case when I execute through my code below. Any help would be much appreciated[image]

Error: [image]

Comment: What kind of file are you uploading? If you can, please share the postman request, I will base on that to setup rest-assured request.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I am trying to upload an image file (with JPEG extension). Here's the cURL....                    curl --location --request POST 'https://api.eu.*****.com/v3.1/documents/' \
--header 'Authorization: Token token=api_live.zsvDeq3vdEf.J_qm225D0***ahMCr*******r_QkUGo_' \
--form 'applicant_id="cacedd93-d1fc-46d2-****-2e2bd40ecc5b"' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/*******/Documents/passport.jpeg"' \
--form 'type="passport"'

Comment: Please edit your question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just miss the mime-type for file upload.

```
RequestSpecBuilder addMultiPart(String controlName, File file, String mimeType)
```

You just put `image/jpeg` for jpeg file.

```
addMultiPart("file", new File(FILE_TO_UPLOAD), "image/jpeg")
```